# Does XSRF-TOKEN must be instatiated by cookie and sent by header?

Tags: spring, http, angular, csrf, electron

Every (c/x)srf protection implementation across the web, which I have seen is done by following flow:

1. server instatiates cookie with token on the client side,
2. client sends X-XSRF-TOKEN header with value read from cookie.

Is it secure to implement point 1 different? Instead sending cookie, sending token in server response (for example header)?

Why I want to implement that this ways is that my REST API is used by two applications:

Single Page Application - written in Angular 2 and 
Native app - written in electron (also Angolar 2 is used)

Browser app is hosted under same url, as API, so there is no problem to retrieve cookie value. But with electron (native) app I have run into issue, when trying to access cookie value (it is impossible, because cookie is set by different host, then app is running on - by default electron app is running from origin `file://` for OSX ie).

The other way of resolving this problem, could be sending cookie, instead X-XSRF-TOKEN header.

Which approach would be better? Or maybe there is some different way to protect against CSRF with native app

PS: all my request are done after authentication process and contains Baerer token.